# python2 TypeError: must be unicode, not str for io module

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I use netsnmp python interface, in netsnmp, it called C extension and print error message, I want to capture this message to string. So I found a blog: [Redirecting all kinds of stdout in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)

But I get in trouble with Python 2.7.x, the code is for Python 3.x

this is a simplily verion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from contextlib import contextmanager
import io
import sys
import os
import tempfile

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirector(stream):
    original_stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    def _redirect_stdout(to_fd):
        sys.stdout.close()
        os.dup2(to_fd, original_stdout_fd)

        #_buf = os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb')
        _buf = io.open(original_stdout_fd, 'wb')   # for BufferWritter object, not file object

        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(_buf)

    saved_stdout_fd = os.dup(original_stdout_fd)
    try:
        tfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b')
        _redirect_stdout(tfile.fileno())
        yield
        _redirect_stdout(saved_stdout_fd)
        tfile.flush()
        tfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        stream.write(tfile.read())
    finally:
        tfile.close()
        os.close(saved_stdout_fd)

f = io.BytesIO()

with stdout_redirector(f):
    print('foobar')
    print(12)
print('Got stdout: "{0}"'.format(f.getvalue().decode('utf-8')))
```

but run this code get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 40, in <module>
    print('foobar')
TypeError: must be unicode, not str
```

I have search several hours and can't fount the reason

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, I think the Python2 code is there in the comment in _redirect_stdout. But there's another line that I think needs to change as well. So change *_redirect_stdout* to:

```
def _redirect_stdout(to_fd):
    sys.stdout.close()
    os.dup2(to_fd, original_stdout_fd)

    _buf = os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb')
    #_buf = io.open(original_stdout_fd, 'wb')   # for BufferWritter object, not file object

    sys.stdout = _buf
```